# RIFT descriptors return NaN in pcl library

Tags: c++, matching, point-cloud-library, descriptor

I am trying to compute the RIFT descriptors of some point clouds for later purposes of matching the descriptors with the ones of other point clouds to check if they belong to the same point cloud.
The problem is that the computation returns NaN values so I cannot match or do anything about it. 
I am using pcl 1.7 and I previously remove NaNs of the pcls with the function pcl::removeNaNFromPointCloud().

The code for computing the descriptors is:

```
pcl::PointCloud<RIFT32>::Ptr processRIFT(
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud) {
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
// -----Read ply file-----
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//Asign pointer to the keypoints cloud
/*pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloudColor(
 new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>& point_cloud = *cloudColor;
 if (pcl::io::loadPLYFile(filename, point_cloud) == -1) {
 cerr << "Was not able to open file \"" << filename << "\".\n";
 printUsage("");
 }*/

// Object for storing the point cloud with intensity value.
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloudIntensityGlobal(
        new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
// Convert the RGB to intensity.
pcl::PointCloudXYZRGBtoXYZI(*cloud, *cloudIntensityGlobal);


pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointWithScale> sifts = processSift(cloud);
//We find the corresponding point of the sift keypoint in the original
//cloud and store it with RGB so that it can be transformed into 
intensity
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_Color(
        new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>& point_cloud_sift = *cloud_Color;
for (int i = 0; i < sifts.points.size(); ++i) {
    pcl::PointWithScale pointSift = sifts.points[i];
    pcl::PointXYZRGB point;
    for (int j = 0; j < cloud->points.size(); ++j) {
        point = cloud->points[j];
        /*if (pointSift.x == point.x && pointSift.y == point.y
         && pointSift.z == point.z) {*/

        if (sqrt(
                pow(pointSift.x - point.x, 2)
                        + pow(pointSift.y - point.y, 2)
                        + pow(pointSift.z - point.z, 2)) < 0.005) {
            point_cloud_sift.push_back(point);
            //std::cout << point.x << " " << point.y << " " << point.z 
<< std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

cout << "Keypoint cloud has " << point_cloud_sift.points.size()
        << " points\n";

// Object for storing the point cloud with intensity value.
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr cloudIntensityKeypoints(
        new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>);
// Object for storing the intensity gradients.
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::IntensityGradient>::Ptr gradients(
        new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::IntensityGradient>);
// Object for storing the normals.
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr normals(new 
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
// Object for storing the RIFT descriptor for each point.
pcl::PointCloud<RIFT32>::Ptr descriptors(new pcl::PointCloud<RIFT32>
());

// Convert the RGB to intensity.
pcl::PointCloudXYZRGBtoXYZI(*cloud_Color, *cloudIntensityKeypoints);
std::cout << "Size: " << cloudIntensityKeypoints->points.size() << 
"\n";

// Estimate the normals.
pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZI, pcl::Normal> normalEstimation;
normalEstimation.setInputCloud(cloudIntensityGlobal);
//normalEstimation.setSearchSurface(cloudIntensityGlobal);
normalEstimation.setRadiusSearch(0.03);
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZI>::Ptr kdtree(
        new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZI>);
normalEstimation.setSearchMethod(kdtree);
normalEstimation.compute(*normals);

// Compute the intensity gradients.
pcl::IntensityGradientEstimation<pcl::PointXYZI, pcl::Normal,
        pcl::IntensityGradient,
        pcl::common::IntensityFieldAccessor<pcl::PointXYZI> > ge;
ge.setInputCloud(cloudIntensityGlobal);
//ge.setSearchSurface(cloudIntensityGlobal);
ge.setInputNormals(normals);
ge.setRadiusSearch(0.03);
ge.compute(*gradients);

// RIFT estimation object.
pcl::RIFTEstimation<pcl::PointXYZI, pcl::IntensityGradient, RIFT32> 
rift;
rift.setInputCloud(cloudIntensityKeypoints);
rift.setSearchSurface(cloudIntensityGlobal);
rift.setSearchMethod(kdtree);
// Set the intensity gradients to use.
rift.setInputGradient(gradients);
// Radius, to get all neighbors within.
rift.setRadiusSearch(0.05);
// Set the number of bins to use in the distance dimension.
rift.setNrDistanceBins(4);
// Set the number of bins to use in the gradient orientation 
dimension.
rift.setNrGradientBins(8);
// Note: you must change the output histogram size to reflect the 
previous values.

rift.compute(*descriptors);
cout << "Computed " << descriptors->points.size() << " RIFT 
descriptors\n";

//matchRIFTFeatures(*descriptors, *descriptors);
return descriptors;
}
```

And the code to match the descriptors is currently this, as KDTreeFlann does not allow me to compile an instance of it with the RIFT type, I dont understand why.

```
int matchRIFTFeatures(pcl::PointCloud<RIFT32>::Ptr descriptors1,
    pcl::PointCloud<RIFT32>::Ptr descriptors2) {
int correspondences = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < descriptors1->points.size(); ++i) {
    RIFT32 des1 = descriptors1->points[i];
    double minDis = 100000000000000000;
    double actDis = 0;
    //Find closest descriptor
    for (int j = 0; j < descriptors2->points.size(); ++j) {
        actDis = distanceRIFT(des1, descriptors2->points[j]);
        //std::cout << "act distance: " << actDis << std::endl;
        if (actDis < minDis) {
            minDis = actDis;
        }
    }
    //std::cout << "min distance: " << minDis << std::endl;
    //If distance between both descriptors is less than threshold we 
found correspondence
    if (minDis < 0.5)
        ++correspondences;
}
return correspondences;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On behalf of the KDTreeFlann problem: Try to include #include "pcl/kdtree/impl/kdtree_flann.hpp" instead of #include "pcl/kdtree/kdtree_flann.h"

Comment: I think I tried but It did not solve the problem. I might just move on from this and try something else